# How to fix for loop Output statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have a for loop statement where i want to print all the information from the list or array in order.

Desired Output:

```
BUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 3 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 4 JBUS: 16 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 5 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 14 ICKT: 2 
IBUS: 2 JBUS: 11 ICKT: 1
```

Unfortunately this is the output I am receiving:

```
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1 
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 2 
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1
```

it seems to be looping through the third array. i think my nested loops are set up incorrectly.

```
FROM_BUS=[1,3,4,5,1,2]
TO_BUS=[12,12,16,12,14,11]
CKT=[1,1,1,1,2,1]
for bus in FROM_BUS:
    for buz in TO_BUS:
        for buc in CKT:
            print('IBUS: {} JBUS: {} ICKT: {} '.format(bus, buz, buc))
```

Comment: You are looping through the lists whereas you want only elements to be shown. Hint: have a look at zip()

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is due to the nested loops. This should work:

```
FROM_BUS=[1,3,4,5,1,2]
TO_BUS=[12,12,16,12,14,11]
CKT=[1,1,1,1,2,1]


for f,t,c in zip(FROM_BUS, TO_BUS, CKT):
    print('IBUS: ' + str(f) + ' JBUS: ' + str(t) + ' ICKT: ' + str(c))
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach using numpy

```
import numpy as np
FROM_BUS=[1,3,4,5,1,2]
TO_BUS=[12,12,16,12,14,11]
CKT=[1,1,1,1,2,1]
a=np.array([FROM_BUS,TO_BUS,CKT])
a=a.transpose()
for i in a:
    print('IBUS: {} JBUS: {} ICKT: {}'.format(*i))
```

Output:

```
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1
IBUS: 3 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1
IBUS: 4 JBUS: 16 ICKT: 1
IBUS: 5 JBUS: 12 ICKT: 1
IBUS: 1 JBUS: 14 ICKT: 2
IBUS: 2 JBUS: 11 ICKT: 1
```